# where do we deregister notifications which are registered in viewDidload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

my requirement is object to have notification registered for its life time(until deallocated) but viewDidUnload method is deprecated, now where do i write statement for notification de-registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically `dealloc`. Though looking at my own code it often makes more sense to add/remove them in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`.

Comment: dealloc will not work with ARC, Requirement is Object should get Notification even if it is not visible(Eg: Navigation controller stack has A and B classes, and B is on top, but A has to get notification)

Comment: Yes it does. The main difference is that you don't need to call `super dealloc` in your implementation. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc).

Answer (score 3):

`dealloc` would be an appropriate place to deregister this.

---

#### Edit to address concerns over ARC

You can implement a custom `dealloc` even when using ARC, but you do not have to deal with instance variables in it. From the [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) guide:

> #### ARC Enforces New Rules
>
> [...]
>
> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed you cannot) release instance variables

Comment: @naresh, yes, it will - though you should also deregister in viewDidLoad before you register to avoid potential duplicates

Comment: Yes, it will, you just don't call it yourself.